# Binding AppWidgets to AppWidgetHost - Android

Tags: android, android-widget, android-appwidget

When you normally want to add an AppWidget in Android there is a list where you need to pick one widget and it binds it to the home screen.

I'm trying to build an app which has its own [appWidgetHost](http://developer.android.com/intl/fr/reference/android/appwidget/AppWidgetHost.html) and specific App Widgets that I built for it.

I have two problems:

1. I would like to be able to automatically bind a widget to my AppWidgetsHost without the user picking from the list.
2. I want to make my own 'pick widgets list' and to load **only** widgets that I have created.

To make it simple; There is my app with my AppWidgets and I want full control in terms of binding a appWidget to the appWidgetHost etc.

3 people asked similar questions in Google forums:

1. [Link 1](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/f24e0f484a79d529)
2. [Link 2](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/231245ba6d1e690f/047b9d3f776d7e54?lnk=gst&q=bindAppWidgetId#047b9d3f776d7e54)
3. [Link 3](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/e4a5b4a87afcf707)

The only answer I found to be a possibility is in link number 2. Paraneet (one of the repliers) said that you can install the app under /system/app instead of /data/app because some security issue. but I'm not sure if it is a reliable solution for production, and I would like to know more about the pros and cons of doing this.

Thanks, Shai.

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunatlly for you (and me), Paraneet is right.

binding appwidget is a sensitive action and thus, to avoid malware it requires the user's consent for the most part however if you install your app into the /system/data folder then you considered part of the OS and you are given a system permission which lets you decide to bind appwidget that you created without any user's involvement.

Comment: @Adam try this:http://coderender.blogspot.ch/2012/01/hosting-android-widgets-my.html

Comment: @Adam try this: http://coderender.blogspot.ch/2012/01/hosting-android-widgets-my.html and this: http://leonardofischer.com/hosting-android-widgets-my-appwidgethost-tutorial/ and this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3635101/how-to-sign-android-app-with-system-signature last link is important for any system app.

Answer (score 1):

In Android O, its possible to pin app widget programmatically. Just watch at example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45655507/4826038)

Also check out Google official [documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45655507/4826038)

Comment: Hey,In case of isRequestPinAppWidgetSupported returning false,  I'm searching for a method to take users to go to wIdget section ( the one we can reqch to by long pressing in the launcher screen and selecting widget )