# Create Widget on Application Installation

Tags: android, android-widget

I was just wondering, is there any way I can make an android widget show up on a user's home screen when they install my application? Also, can I let them choose to create a widget from within my application?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Binding AppWidgets to AppWidgetHost - Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4258579/binding-appwidgets-to-appwidgethost-android)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I was just wondering, is there any way I can make an android widget show up on a user's home screen when they install my application?

No, sorry. None of your code gets executed upon install.

> Also, can I let them choose to create a widget from within my application?

No, sorry. Only the home screen can add app widgets to the home screen.

Comment: Ok i agree with your answer but i am surprising how this app made this function work https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cleanmaster.mguard

Comment: it has a 1 tap boost function when click on icon in home screen here i already ask a question about smiler functionality may you answer this..? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23004624/is-it-is-possible-to-make-android-app-launcher-icon-animated-when-i-click-on-it/23004676#23004676

Comment: @Hardik, I think, clean master not create any widget, rather it creates the shortcut of application

Comment: @ErKimmiDhingra Yes Clean master creating shortcut of application but my question was how they animating shortcut icon. see my answer in above link

Comment: @CommonsWare what if my app is launcher?

Answer (score 1):

Where is no way to get callback upon installation. But in Android O you can pin your widget on first launch of your application.

```
AppWidgetManager mAppWidgetManager =
    context.getSystemService(AppWidgetManager.class);

AppWidgetProviderInfo myWidgetProviderInfo = new AppWidgetProviderInfo();
ComponentName myProvider = myWidgetProviderInfo.provider;

if (mAppWidgetManager.isRequestPinAppWidgetSupported()) {
  // Create the PendingIntent object only if your app needs to be notified
  // that the user allowed the widget to be pinned. Note that, if the pinning
  // operation fails, your app isn't notified.
  Intent pinnedWidgetCallbackIntent = new Intent( ... );

  // Configure the intent so that your app's broadcast receiver gets
  // the callback successfully. This callback receives the ID of the
  // newly-pinned widget (EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID).
  PendingIntent successCallback = PendingIntent.createBroadcast(context, 0,
          pinnedWidgetCallbackIntent);

  mAppWidgetManager.requestPinAppWidget(myProvider, null,
           successCallback.getIntentSender());
}
```

Also check out Google official [documentation](https://developer.android.com/preview/features/pinning-shortcuts-widgets.html#widgets)