# How to Create Widget when press button on application (Android)

Tags: android, widget

I must make something like that.
I run my application and press button "Create widget" and the widget is created on Home screen.

I don't know how to do it, Just i know how to take widget to home screen when i choose my widget in widgets menu and write text what i want in this widget
And I know how to run ConfigureActivity on my application but when i writte some text and press add "widget" it don't create. I think i don't have any id's to create widget but how to get that? Random or something.
I used in Android Studio New > Widget > App Widget.

Comment: Take a look at the following thread:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16100926/how-to-add-a-widget-to-the-android-home-screen-from-my-app

Comment: Thank's this help a lot

Answer (score 0):

> I run my application and press button "Create widget" and the widget is created on Home screen.

This is not possible. The only app that can add an app widget to the home screen is the home screen itself.

Comment: In windows phone I can do this ;/