How to directly guide users to add my app's widget from an activity?
How can I add a button in an activity of my Android app, so that when the user clicks on it, they are directly taken to the widget selection screen, and my app's widget is displayed prominently and differently from other widgets, allowing the user to easily find and add it to the home screen without having to search among other widgets?
I tried using
AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_PICK,

but it wasn't helpful.

Look at this method:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16100926/how-to-add-a-widget-to-the-android-home-screen-from-my-app
