# Is it is possible to make android app launcher icon animated when i click on it?

Tags: android, animation, widget, icons

I need a functionality for my app when i click on app launcher icon it should be animated.

Also I need click event of it so i can do whatever operation on that.

**TRIED:**

I have tried widget but i don't have an idea how exactly do that.

Please help me if you have any suggestion for this or any idea how to make this type of functionality.

Comment: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/k7T7lPttyko

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out how to achieve animation on app icon like other app doing.

1. create shortcut or of your app you will need this permission.

`<uses-permission` `android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.INSTALL_SHORTCUT" />`

1. you need to create transparent activity by specifying `Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar` Theme. This activity will responsible for animation that we want to achieve when user click on shortcut of app.
2. now we can show animation over shortcut icon by computing position of shortcut. this can be done using `ShortcutInfo` and `ShortcutManager`. To give support all android version there is`ShortcutInfoCompat`class available. find more [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/pm/ShortcutInfoCompat).

Comment: How exactly can we compute the position of shortcut?

Answer (score -1):

Just a suggestion did you consider the possibility of using a "gif" image?

And trying to replace images on mouse event.

Haven't tried it though.

Comment: how you can replace image on launcher icon tell me?

Comment: Thats why I had mentioned it as "a suggestion" I've never tried it. I feel like there may be another way.

How about action scripts? just try some digging. I'm not sure if it's possible.

Comment: Then why this stuff of yours comes under ans ,If you are suggesting something and not sure about it then it should be under comments section

Comment: Ok @Auto-Droid ツ please edit it and try posting it as a comment if you have the spare time. If you have any suggestions go ahead, lead the way.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1103027/how-to-change-an-application-icon-programmatically-in-android link to change app icon but functionality varies on devices