# How to add an widget in code to the home screen

Tags: android, android-appwidget, launcher

I am trying to write a simple launcher application.In that I am trying to add a default widget like android clock.I am loading all the information of default widgets like x,y positions,width and height and package informations.After loading this I am getting the appwidgetId for the homescreen.The code is like this.

```
public void bindAppWidgets(Launcher.DesktopBinder binder,
                LinkedList<WidgetInfo> appWidgets) {
            if (!appWidgets.isEmpty()) {
                for(int k=0;k<appWidgets.size();k++){
                    final WidgetInfo item = appWidgets.get(k);
                    System.out.println("Item to be added in the view :::::::::"+item.toString());
                    int appWidgetId = item.appWidgetId;
                    if(item.itemType == LauncherProvider.Widgets.ITEM_TYPE_DEFAULT_APPWIDGET){
                        bindDefaultAppwidgets(item);
                        continue;
                        item.appWidgetId=mAppWidgetHost.allocateAppWidgetId();
                        LauncherModel.updateItemInDatabase(getApplicationContext(), item);
                        appWidgetId=item.appWidgetId;
                    }

                    final AppWidgetProviderInfo appWidgetInfo = mAppWidgetManager.getAppWidgetInfo(appWidgetId);
                    System.out.println("the Appwidget info is*******"+appWidgetInfo);
                    item.hostView =(LauncherAppWidgetHostView) mAppWidgetHost.createView(this, appWidgetId, appWidgetInfo);

                    if (LOGD) {
                        d(TAG, String.format("about to setAppWidget for id=%d, info=%s", appWidgetId,
                                appWidgetInfo));
                    }

                    item.hostView.setAppWidget(appWidgetId, appWidgetInfo);
                    item.hostView.setTag(item);
                    MyAbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams lp=new MyAbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams(item.spanX, item.spanY, item.cellX, item.cellY);
                    System.out.println("after load the hostview ::::::::::: :::::::::"+item.toString());
                    mDragLayer.addView(item.hostView,lp);
                }
                mDragLayer.requestLayout();
            }

        }
```

Now I am getting null value for the widgets in AppWidgetProviderInfo.because of that I couldn't load the hostview in homescreen.Can any one suggest me to add the widget in home screen with out appwidgetpicker app.

Answer (score 1):

such a feature cannot be used unless the launcher has a special permission and is a system app  (which will let it to use this permission).

there are plenty of places that will tell you the same , by simply searching for "bindAppWidgetId" . here's an example:
[Binding AppWidgets to AppWidgetHost - Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4258579/binding-appwidgets-to-appwidgethost-android)
the reason for this is security .

i think that even for your own app widgets , you cannot bind . however, you can always mimic the app-widgets by creating custom views instead. they have much more power than appwidgets , so you can do anything you wish there.